# Rails Can't Update Nested Child Resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I'm working on a project that uses a Rails front-end to send updated data to a Rails back-end.

The form data I'm trying to PATCH includes updated data for the resource, along with updates to a nested, child resource.

In this scenario, a user interacts with a form that contains data for a writer, which has many jobs, all of which are nested within the form as well.

Data contains potential updates to the writer, one/many/all of the writers' jobs, or both.

**writer.rb**

```
class Writer < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :jobs, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :writer
   has_many :genre_tags, dependent: :destroy
   has_many :genres, :through => :genre_tags

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :genre_tags, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :jobs, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
end
```

**job.rb**

```
class Job < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :writer, inverse_of: :jobs
   validates_uniqueness_of :outlet_id, scope: [:writer_id]
   validates :outlet_id, presence: true
end
```

**writers_controller.rb**

```
 def update
   @writer = Writer.where(inactive:false).find(params[:id])

   if @writer.update(writer_params)
     render json: {writer: @writer, notice: 'Writer was successfully updated.'}
   else
     render json: {errors:Rails.logger.info(@writer.errors.inspect), status: :unprocessable_entity }
   end

   def writer_params
     params.require(:writer).permit(:f_name,:l_name, :email_personal, :city, :state, :country_id,:twitter, :linkedin, :freelance, :notes, :user_id, jobs_attributes: [:id, :outlet_id, :email_work, :position, :outlet_profile, :key_contact, :_destroy, presstype_tags_attributes: [:id, :presstype_id, :_destroy]], genre_tags_attributes: [:id, :writer_id, :genre_id, :_destroy])
   end

end
```

The problem is that, when I PATCH this data, I get a validation error:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fef651e8410 @base=#<Writer id: 2, f_name:  "Chet", l_name: 
"Hamper", city: "Las Vegas", state: "NV", country_id: 229, 
twitter: "AndreasHale", linkedin: "andreashale", 
freelance: false, flagged: nil, inactive: false, 
notes: nil, created_at: "2017-02-19 15:38:55", 
updated_at: "2017-02-25 16:17:18", user_id: 1, 
email_personal: nil, twitter_followers: nil, 
personal_website: "N/A">, 
@messages={:"jobs.presstype_tags.job_id"=>["can't be blank"],
:"jobs.outlet_id"=>["has already been taken"], 
:"genre_tags.genre_id"=>["has already been taken"]}, 
@details={"jobs.presstype_tags.job_id"=>[{:error=>:blank}], "jobs.outlet_id"=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>2}], 
"genre_tags.genre_id"=>[{:error=>:taken, :value=>6}, {:error=>:taken, :value=>9}, {:error=>:taken, :value=>10}, {:error=>:taken, :value=>11}]}>
```

Unless I'm mistaken, ActiveRecord is telling me I am trying to create new, nested attributes even though they already exist. I'm not trying to overwrite these records, just to, when they do exist, update their attributes.

Any clues on how I can specify that I'm not trying to overwrite anything?

**UPDATE**

It turns out the structure of my form data didn't match the jobs_attributes, genre_tags_attributes, and presstype_tags_attributes params, so I wound up restructuring my form to match it exactly, and now it works like a charm!

Comment: Could you please share the form parameters which are send to update method ?

Comment: @Sasidaran so sorry, but do you mean you'd like me to share the actual PATCH request, or the form itself?